# Include list values in a single data row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datagrid

I have a class much like the following:

```
public class foo_class
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public List<int> d { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is display a collection of this class in a jquery grid, displaying all elements of d in the same row as a, b and c, like so:

```
a1 | b1 | c1 | d1[0] | d1[1] | d1[2] | ...
a2 | b2 | c2 | d2[0] | d2[1] | d2[2] | ...
a3 | b3 | c3 | d3[0] | d3[1] | d3[2] | ...
```

The problem is that the d list is not a fixed size; in fact, its size can change at runtime depending on what the user does.

The best I have come up with so far is the following, using the jqwidgets grid (I also have the same issue with the Telerik Kendo grid):

```
var source =
{
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'a', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'b', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'c', type: 'string' },
    ],
    id: 'id',
    localdata: data.foo
};

var myColumns = [
        { datafield: "a", text: "a", width: 60 },
        { datafield: "b", text: "b", width: 250 },
        { datafield: "c", text: "c", width: 75 },
];

for (i = 0; i < data.d.Count; i++) {
    source.datafields.push({ name: "d[" + i + "]", type: "int", map: "d[" + i + "]>val" });
    myColumns.push({ datafield: "d[" + i + "]", text: i, width: 75 });
};

var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
{
    source: dataAdapter,
    columns: myColumns
});
```

This displays the a, b, c data and the columns for d, but the grid cells for the d values are blank.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am a newbie to jquery stuff.

Comment: can you also show how `data` looks like ?

Comment: The first section of this post has the class description of the data that is being bound to the grid.  Is there anything more specific I can include?  It is a simplification of my actual code, but the "data" returned is accurate.  It is just not binding to the grid properly.